# Fir the anchor tag in li tag using flexbox

Tags: html, css, html-lists, anchor

I want anchor element to have width: 100% inside li tag using flexbox. Seems it doesn't. How to do this? Here green borders is for li elements (#part_1 nav ul li) and white borders for anchor elements (#part_1 nav ul li a).
[image: How it looks like]
Here is HTML:

```
<nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And styles:

```
#part_1 nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;

    flex: .15 .15 15%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: #313030;
}

#part_1 nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;

    flex: 0 1 50%;
}

#part_1 nav ul li {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;

    padding: 0 3%;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

#part_1 nav ul li a {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    flex: 1 0 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e0e0e0;

    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1em;

    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: try to remove the padding `padding: 0 3%;` from the list-items

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan but i need some space between text edge and li edge

Comment: then apply the padding to the inner link

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan now, anchor's border is wider than li's border and while using `justify-content: center;` for ul tag, li elements are overlapping each other...

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/ruhuzQP)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan please help :)